# Flushing content to AWS S3 with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Java application that writes content to a file in a AWS S3 bucket.

The writer is created with this code

```
SequenceWriter getBufferedWriter(final ObjectWriter newWriter)
                throws IOException {
            var key = "myFile.csv";

            manager = new StreamTransferManager(bucket, key, client.getClient()).numStreams(1)
                    .numUploadThreads(1)
                    .queueCapacity(1)
                    .partSize(PART_SIZE_MB);
            outputStream = manager.getMultiPartOutputStreams()
                    .get(0);
            return newWriter.writeValues(outputStream);
        }
```

Then I write values with

```
writer.writeValue(myData);
```

The application works fine, and when it is finished, the data is in the S3 file. However, I'd like to have the content written (and flushed) while the application is running, so if for any reason the application crashes, I still get partial content in the file.

I'd actually like to "flush" it programmatically, so when a certain event occurs in my application, I force the flush

I've tried using `writer.flush()` but it didn't achieve what I wanted.

How can I force the content to be written to S3?

Comment: If you want the data to be uploaded "earlier" reduce the `partSize`.

Comment: I'd actually like to "flush" it programmatically, so when a certain event occurs in my application, I force the flush (I'll add it to the question).

Comment: You can't. S3 is an object store, not a filesystem. Objects become available in S3 when they have been fully written, not before. You could play around with multi-part uploads and recover the upload after failure, but this doesn't seem to be what you're asking for (and isn't going to happen automatically in any case). If you need to capture incremental results, either use a filesystem such as EFS, or write smaller files and combine later.